# query sorted by letter without like() - laravel | Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::LIKE()

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

where is the mistake?

I need it to be organized in alphabetical order, but it shows everything repeated, and I need the data to be shown under its letter, follows code:

[print dashboar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ah6.png)

**code controller**

```
  /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $contacts = DB::table('contacts')->where('name', $user_name)->first();
        return view('home', compact('contacts', 'user_name'));
    }
```

**view code html**

```
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->
                    <li class="pt-3 pb-3 sticky p-3 b-b white">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-success gradient">C</span>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Single contact -->
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u1.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small> {{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">D</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>{{$contacts->first_name}}Alexander Pierce</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small>{{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                     <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">E</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small>{{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">F</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small> {{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">G</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small>{{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">H</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small>{{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <!-- Alphabet with number of contacts -->                               
                    <li class="my-4">
                        <span class="badge r-3 badge-danger purple">I</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="my-1">
                        <div class="card no-b p-3">
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="image mr-3  float-left">
                                    <img class="w-40px" src="assets/img/dummy/u2.png" alt="User Image">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <strong>{{$contacts->first_name}}</strong>
                                    </div>
                                    <small>{{$contacts->first_name}}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I need the lyrics to disappear if there is nothing in the database, I tried using @foreach but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's assume you have something like this that returns all the users from your index method in your UsersController

```
public function index()
  {
   //remember to import App\User which is your user model on top of this controller
   $users = User::all(); //this is supposed to get all the users
   return view('users.index', compact('users.page', 'users'));
  }
  // in your index.blade.php page you should do this to check if the users return are empty or not
 @if(isset($users))
    //show users
 @else
   //show add button
 @endif;
```

Comment: I put in the end what I was doing, take a look there

Comment: Try and post your entire method

Comment: contacts are loaded into the menu along with sidbar, they are not loaded on a separate page, so it makes it difficult to use the controller.

Comment: I put a new code, which I'm developing right now, take a look there please

Comment: Are your db queries returning the exact values you want?

Comment: before returned now I get: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

Comment: $contacts = DB::table('contacts')->where('name', Auth::user()->nome)->first();
        return view('home', compact('contacts'));

Comment: @foreach($contacts as $contact) <small> {{$contacts->first_name}}</small> @endforeach

Comment: I am trying to filter by the name of the logged in user but I stopped in this error, what can it be?